# Detect a circular shape inside image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, shapes

Whats the fastest way to detect these circular shapes in a image?

[image: Red Circle to be detected]

The radius is always between(80-100mm). Background is always white. And the circle will always be in center.

I have tried [Hough Transform](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9168-detect-circles-with-various-radii-in-grayscale-image-via-hough-transform) but I couldn't really get it to work. I am new to this, and I get a feeling like *Hough Transform* is a overkill for this. Kindly suggest me the right approach to do this.
[image]

---

UPDATE

Here is what I got after applying hough transform.

I have used the algorithm mentioned [here](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9168-detect-circles-with-various-radii-in-grayscale-image-via-hough-transform).

Following is the relevant code from the bigger algorithm

```
% applying Hough Below
[accum, circen, cirrad] = ...
    CircularHough_Grd(gR, [89 93],...
    17.4, 13, 1);   % this executes in 0.72 sec

% Lets see what we got
imshow(gR);
hold on;
plot(circen(:,1), circen(:,2), 'r+');
for ii = 1 : size(circen, 1)
    rectangle('Position',[circen(ii,1) - cirrad(ii), circen(ii,2) - cirrad(ii), 2*cirrad(ii), 2*cirrad(ii)],...
        'Curvature', [1,1], 'edgecolor', 'b', 'linewidth', 1.5);
end
hold off;
```

[image]

The meaningful circle is the one in the middle.

Comment: Can you please show your own attempts first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I propose:
 1. convert to gray image, enhancing the "difference from white"

```
gimg = min( img, [], 3 );
```

[image]
 2. Threshold to remove white area

```
BW = im2bw( gimg, .4 );
```

[image]
 3. Get area and centroid porperties of image regions

```
st = regionprops( ~BW, 'Area', 'Centroid', 'PixelIdxList' );
```

4. select only large enough regions

```
sel = [st.Area] > numel(BW)*0.025; % at least 2.5% of image size
st = st(sel);
```

5. compute region distance to center of image

```
cntr = .5 * [size(BW,2) size(BW,1)]; % X-Y coordinates and NOT Row/Col
d = sqrt( sum( bsxfun(@minus,vertcat( st.Centroid ), cntr ).^2, 2 ) );
```

6. pick the region closest to center

```
[mn idx] = min(d);
```

7. Create a mask

```
res = false(size(BW)); 
res( st(idx).PixelIdxList ) = true;
```

[image]

You might also consider using other region properties (e.g., `'Eccentricity'`) to better reject regions that are not circular.

Comment: In order to be extra sure that you're getting a circle, you could check to see that the ratio of it's area to it's maximum radius is high.

Comment: @Shai This is a **$niper shot**. The circle's won't know what hit'em. It takes 0.04sec only(too less as compared to the hough transform thing that i was doing)! As the next step I'll enclose the white imperfect circle inside a square and get its center and approximate a better circle and then use that circle as a mask and then try to obtain the color of the circle. Is this approach right? or is there a ready_made method for doing that ?

Comment: @wy - take a look at `regionprops` and what it can offer you. In my code you already have the center of the circle in `'Centroid'` field of `st` struct array. Depending on the accuracy you need you'll have to find a method to estimate the radius of the circle. If its the color you want - then you don't need to estimate a circle - the mask `res` is all you need: `t = reshape( img, [], 3); c = mean( t(res,:), 1 )` will give you the mean color of masked pixels.

Comment: @Shai `reshape( img, [], 3)` throws *Product of known dimensions, 3, not divisible into total number of elements, 450800.* error. I think I'll need to truncate or stuff the *img* array to make its size divisible by 3.

Comment: @wy if number of elements of  your **color** image is not divisible by 3 then this is wierd: you should have 3rd dimension of size 3 corresponding to R, G and B components of each pixel.

Comment: @Shai I obtained the snaps via `myImg =  getsnapshot(videoinput_obj_640_480)` the snaps were `640x480x3 uint8` array. And I did *imshow(myImg)* then *save as* these images into *jpg* format and somehow they become `566x805x3 uint8` array.

Comment: @wy as long as they got `x3` at the end: `t = reshape( myImg, [], 3 ); c = mean( t(res,:), 1 )` should give you the mean RGB values of the circle.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42598/discussion-between-vvy-and-shai)

Answer (score 4):

If your matlab version is R2012a or later, the image processing tool box includes the function `imfindcircles` that is used to detect circles in the image.

```
filen='https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmBp1.jpg';  % your original image
I=imread(filen);

I=im2bw(I(:,:,3));  % convert to gray scale
Rmin=50;Rmax=100;  % circle radius range
[centersDark, radiiDark] = imfindcircles(I, [Rmin Rmax], ...
                                        'ObjectPolarity','dark','sensitivity',0.93)
imagesc(I),hold on
viscircles(centersDark, radiiDark,'LineStyle','--');hold off
```

The result:
[image]

Actually this function also applies Hough transform, I think it's similar with yours. One thing you may need to note is,  the threshold corresponding to the sensitivity in Hough has great impact on the detecting result. Too high sensitivity leads to detecting more circles, including weak or partially obscured ones, at the risk of a higher false detection rate, which was exactly what you obtained.

Comment: this is quite an overkill. See wy's [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400873/detect-a-circular-shape-inside-image-in-matlab/20402175?noredirect=1#comment30468926_20402175) on running times.

Comment: @lennon310 I have R2010a. Can I obtain `imfindcircles` for my release ? How much time this script takes to get the circle?

Comment: it should be included in imaging processing toolbox then. I takes ~0.7s to implement imfindcircles, while ~0.05s for regionprops. So if you have a huge amount of image to be processed, the speed may be much slower.