# How can I locate the center of each circle in the image using toolbox in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to pick the center of each visible circle on the graph. How can I use Matlab to realize that automatically? i.e. tracing the boundary of the circle and then find the center of the area?

The image to work on
[image: The image to work on is here]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! There are some toolboxes in Matlab you could use to get the circles and them define the center point. Here you can find a possible way: https://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/boundarymask.html

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400873/detect-a-circular-shape-inside-image-in-matlab ?